# Generating resource files for application based on default resource files

Tags: visual-studio, resources, localization, globalization

I have a .net application that currently has resource files for all it's content, one per .aspx and .ascx. Currently there are only resource files for english.

I now need to add resource files for another language which means I need to replicate all the resource files with just the keys and no values, files named with the correct culture extension eg es for spainish.

My application is built against the .net 3.5 framework in VS2008.

Is there any way of automatically creating/generating the new resource files, in the format detailed above for the entire solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this free [command line tool](http://www.screwturn.eu/ResxSync.ashx) or a more sophisticated service like [Amanuens](http://amanuens.com).

Disclaimer: I've built the tool and my company is behind the service I've linked.